# Extract the names of sf objects from a list in R

Tags: r, list, r-sf, names

I am trying to extract the names of the objects in a list, they are all sf. So I cannot use names.

```
`subte_estaciones <- st_read("http://bitsandbricks.github.io/data/subte_estaciones.geojson")

Universidades = read.csv("C:/Users/sixto/OneDrive/Documentos/GCBA/Alquiler Social/Universidades.csv")
Universidades <- Universidades %>%  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

trenes = st_read("https://cdn.buenosaires.gob.ar/datosabiertos/datasets/transporte-y-obras-publicas/estaciones-ferrocarril/estaciones-de-ferrocarril.geojson")

object_list = list(subte_estaciones , trenes , Universidades  )  

names(object_list)
```

NULL

I need object names in a vector to replace column names.

I tried almost everything to no avail.

object_names <- c()

```
# Use a for loop to iterate through the list and store the names of the objects in the new vector
for(i in 1:length(object_list)) {
    object_names[i] <- paste0(deparse(substitute(object_list[[i]])),i)
}
# Print the new vector of object names
object_names


# Create a new vector to store the names of the sf objects
object_names <- c()

# Use a for loop to iterate through the list and store the names of the objects in the new vector
for(i in 1:length(object_list)) {
    object_names[i] <- paste0("sf_object_",i)
}

# Print the new vector of object names
object_names
```

Comment: Let's start with you have a backtick at the beginning of subte_estaciones, whose partner in R compiler crime prevention seems missing. The absence of `object_list` may explain your subsequent difficulties with their `names(object_list)`. Are there perhaps some lines of code that coalesce, say `object_list <- list(subte_estaciones = subte_estaciones, Universidades = Univerdades, trenes = trenes)` that didn't make it to the party, quienes no estuvieron escritan ensima. If you `names(trenes)`, likely there'll be some names. Sorry, listening to Hendrix and makes me think I speak spanish. Perdoname

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Yes Im sorry, Object list is created by this


```{r}
object_list = list(subte_estaciones , trenes , Universidades  )

```

Comment: Sorry, but what is exactly your expected result? `object_list` is an unnamed list that you are creating yourself.`

 So if instead of `object_list = list(subte_estaciones , trenes , Universidades)` you do `object_list = list(sf1 = subte_estaciones , sf2= trenes , sf3=Universidades)` you get  `[1] "sf1" "sf2" "sf3"` with `names(object_list)`.

Comment: That is correct it is neccesary to name the objects in the list! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

To get the names of the object_list it is necessary to first name the objects in the list

```
object_list= list(subte_estaciones = subte_estaciones,trenes = trenes, Universidades = Universidades)
names = names(object_list)
names
[1] "subte_estaciones" "Universidades"    "trenes"
```